# Do passenger missions count as "Trade"?

Tags: elite-dangerous, elite-dangerous-horizons

Most gameplay in *E:D* is broken down into three disciplines: Combat, Exploration, and Trade.

While Trade missions usually center around the buying and selling of cargo, people can also be transported via passenger missions (and in the case of Imperial slaves, people can also be cargo, but those are not considered passenger missions).

In what situation(s) does *E:D* consider passenger missions as Trade missions?

Comment: @Sjoerd i exclusively do passenger missions now, and my trade rank is rising, while my exploration rank is not. My source here is personal experience only. I tested this myself (on Xbox) because I couldnt find this information elsewhere .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some missions count towards exploration rank (collect data and sightseeing adventures), some count towards trade rank (seeking transport).

When taking a passenger mission, you can see what is the recommended rank - if it is a trader rank (e.g. mostly penniless), then it will count towards trade rank, if it is an explorer rank (e.g. mostly aimless), then it will count towards exploration rank.

Comment: Interesting, i only do the transport type so i never noticed the difference. I mainly posted this because i was surprised it doesnt give you vouchers for powerplay.

Comment: I've edited my answer as well to avoid confusion, thanks for clarification

Comment: @Dpeif You can give credit to Gedas for providing the correct answer, by selecting it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Sjoerd im aware of how the site works, but i wasnt just asking about rank. i upvoted though, as he contributed, and i gave him credit in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the answer by @Gedas, only "Transport" type passenger missions will contribute to your Trade rank.

Unfortunately, passenger missions do not count towards your "profits from trade" statistic in the Status panel, nor do they count towards any Powerplay benefits concerning trade vouchers, such as the Rank 2 benefit from Edmund Mahon.

Comment: @Sjoerd i see what you mean, edited to clarify in the first sentence.

Comment: After your edit, your answer is basically a repeat of Gedas' answer.